# Связать разделы каталога и контент страницы в битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте!
Кто-нибудь знает, можно ли сделать на битриксе такое: в левой части страницы каталог книг с подкатегориями.. и чтобы по нажатию на каталог в контенте страницы отражались все книги по этой категории? Получается, на странице есть catalog.list с разделами,а в контенте - new.list. Как их связать примерно, чтобы логично все показывалось?

Answer (score 1):

В часть где контент (на главной странице каталога) нужно кинуть комплексный компонент `bitrix:catalog`, у инфоблока прописать правильно пути до `URL страницы информационного блока, URL страницы раздела, URL страницы детального просмотра`, дальше слева также выставить нужный инфоблок. Суть в чем - когда слева кликают по ссылке на категорию то отрабатывает в части контента `bitrix:catalog.section.list`, который должен выводить все товары из данной категории.

Comment: то есть в контент страницы нужен компонент не news.list а саtalog.list?
есть по идее один инфоблок Каталог в нем разделы Видео, Книги, Игры..у них свои подразделы, в подразделах элементы..
а можно настроить catalog.list в левой части на вывод только разделов, и при кликания на подраздел перенести все элементы этого раздела в catalog.list контента страницы? получается оба catalog.list настроены на один и тот же инфоблок, только на разные его части?? так можно?

Comment: если в контентой части поставить catalog.list, то при клики на товар они не будут отображаться, в контентной части нужно bitrix:catalog

Comment: все-таки непонятно..
в левой части просто каталог с разделами - это какой должен быть компонент?
а в рабочей части (#WORK_AREA#) должны показываться активного раздела - это какой компонент тоже?

Comment: bitrix:catalog в контентной части, слева bitrix:catalog.section, проще все чтобы научиться - установить тестовые данный и посмотреть как там сделано

Comment: как установить тестовые данные?

Comment: проще всего скачать тестовую версию битрикс - поставить на локальный компьютер